# DataGridView Multithread update crash

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I am facing an issue with updating DataGridView while each thread operates on different row, it all time crash.

Here is example of what I try to do, but honestly I don't know how to fix it.

Researched invoke method but doesn't work :(

```
private void threadingFunction()
{
    int ThreadsNumber = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myFunction(i)));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private void myFunction(int i)
{
    doSomething()
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "1";
    doSomething();
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "2";
    doSomething();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "3";
    doSomething();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "4";
    doSomething();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "5";
    doSomething();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "6";
}
```

---

Update

I figured out, when in same time thread1 update datagridview, and thread2 started same time want do same action take or fill datagrid view cell, it throw errors, "out of index", "error instance of object" etc. Anyone know how to fix this issue, because it crash my whole program.. and cant figure out how to correctly invoke implement to this .

here code I am testing:

```
private void threadingFunction()
        {
            int ThreadsNumber = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber - 1; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myFunction(i)));
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private void myFunction(int i)
        {

            var geg = dataGridView1[4, i].Value.ToString();
            dataGridView1[5, i].Value = geg;

            //dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "2";


            //dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "3";


            //dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "4";


            //dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "5";


            //dataGridView1[4, i].Value = "6";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Do you get an Exception when it crashes?

Comment: What do you mean invoke doesn't work? What did you try exactly? Accessing UI components from other threads will not work directly.

Comment: Invoke should solve your cross threading issue.  What error are you getting.

Comment: I get this error https://prnt.sc/12799zo  and this  https://prnt.sc/1279br9  and Im sure row exist and not out of range, because half time work fine till it crash.

Comment: You'd better set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true`. It protects you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: this doesnt work sadly Ive tested it

Comment: @AdultMarketing - You cannot access or update a UI element from any thread other than the one that created it. That thread is usually the one and only UI thread. You can do background processing on other threads, but you can't touch any UI control in the background.

Comment: @AdultMarketing multithreading is difficult. Unless you have at least a basic understanding of the concepts, you are advised to avoid it. In case you want to gain this understanding, here is a great online resource: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari.